# how to create a task for app bundle in bamboo

Tags: bamboo, artifacts, android-app-bundle

Does anybody know how to create a script task in bamboo to include the android app bundle. 
https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/configuring-tasks-289277036.html Referred this link. Could anyone help

Answer (score 0):

Modify the script to read command line arguments.  Then pass the app bundle in as a command line argument.

Answer (score 0):

You can

- use a ScriptTask and execute a gradle task (using the gradle wrapper)
- buy the [Groovy Task for Bamboo plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/772506/groovy-tasks-for-bamboo?hosting=server&tab=overview&_ga=2.256273544.2004470417.1564129496-388779068.1563797550)

With the ScriptTask just run a gradle task.
For example if you want to build the app-bundle just use:

```
./gradlew bundleRelease
```